# Delete duplicate / doubloons rows

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am trying to setup a VBA code to open sheet called "data" and delete the entire row if the data of column A is not unique (was already in other row of column A).

Using the example below I would keep just the rows 2, 6, 8 and 11. And the headers of course.

[image]

```
Sub delete_duplicates_on_column_A()
    ' delete_duplicates_on_column_A Macro '
    Columns("A:E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$22").RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Have to tried to code anything ?

Comment: But I would like to make it work for any data on column A, without specify cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will :

delete the duplicates of the **Columns A to E** (`A:E`you can extend it), 
taking into consideration only **Columns B to E** (`Array(2, 3, 4, 5)` you can tune it too) to determine if you have doubloons in your data!

```
Sub test_Gonzalo()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:E")
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates _
            Columns:=Array(2, 3, 4, 5), _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP stated that the duplicate criteria is only column A... Although the example given is confusing...

Comment: That's right, the duplication criteria is just for the data on Column A. Actually the data in Column A is a variable that I dont know. How could change the code to work with any type of content? Thanks

Comment: Basically what I am trying to achieve is that if the rows belows have the same data of A column any of the column A rows above, the row should be deleted.

Comment: @A.S.H : Yes, I know and that is what the code does, it'll delete the duplicates of the Columns A to E, taking into consideration only Column B to E (2, 3, 4, 5). So it is exactly what was asked. @ Gonzalo : This will work on any type of data.

Comment: Well, I might be the one confused, after all :)

Comment: @A.S.H : Apparently, you weren't the only one, so I must have interpreted the OP to have so *data meaning*, see other answer and my comment! ;)

Comment: Never mind my previous comments, I did not refresh and see your explanations before writing.  My bad.

Comment: @ScottCraner : No problems, I added them afterwards, I should have included them at start for the OP to understand the meaning of the code! ;)